# Location permission always denied on Android sdk 33

Tags: android, permissions

i'm currently trying to migrate my App to target SDK 33.
When I try to request location permissions (coarse or fine, always the same problem) it is always denied without even showing the request dialog.

I've included both loaction permissions in the Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In my Activity, I register a ResultContract:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> locationPermissionRequest =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts
                            .RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
                        Boolean fineLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
                        Boolean coarseLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false);
                        if (fineLocationGranted != null && fineLocationGranted) {
                            // Precise location access granted.
                            Log.d(TAG, "permissions granted");
                            //Do Stuff here
                        } else if (coarseLocationGranted != null && coarseLocationGranted) {
                            // Only approximate location access granted.
                            Log.d(TAG, "Only approximate location access granted");
                        } else {
                            // No location access granted.
                            Log.e(TAG, "location permission denied");
                        }
                    }
            );
```

after checking if the permissions are already granted and displaying a dialog to the user, I request the permissions:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DashboardActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DashboardActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ModalDialog permissionInfoDialog = null;
                        ModalDialog.Builder permissionInfoDialogBuilder = new ModalDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this);
                        permissionInfoDialogBuilder.setType(ModalDialog.Type.DEFAULT_INFO)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "requesting location permission");
                                        locationPermissionRequest.launch(new String[]{
                                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                                        });

                                    }
                                })
                                .setTextNegative(android.R.string.cancel)
                                .setTitle(R.string.dashboard_request_location_permission_title)
                                .setMessage(R.string.dashboard_request_location_permission_text)
                                .setCloseable(false);
                        permissionInfoDialog = permissionInfoDialogBuilder.create();
                        permissionInfoDialog.show();
                        return;
                    }
```

The code above is copied from the Android docs (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#location) and works for requesting camera and bluetooth permissions. Somehow it does not work for location permissions.

Before the migration to sdk 33 (it was 32 before) everything worked fine.
Is there anything i'm missing? According to the docs, this should work.

Regards and thanks in advance

Herrmann_wst

Comment: is your project a multi-module app? if so, declare the fine and coarse location permission in the app module manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should first ask for COARSE.

And only after the user granted that ask for FINE.

Comment: I've tried only requesting COARSE. Same result, it gets denied without even asking.

Comment: Go to settings of your app. Take back all location permissions. Then ask for coarse.

Comment: I don't have the option to take back location permission since they are not shown in the settings (only the camera and bluetooth permissions are shown and i can revoke them).  I've completley removed and reinsatalled the app, then asked for coarse. Same result, permission denied without asking.

Comment: Mmmm. Strange that it lacks in Setting. I have no idea at the moment.

Comment: Found the solution. But thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
one of my included modules had the following lines in its manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

somehow even if I include the permissions in the app manifest without the sdk restrictions, android does not grant the permissions. It looks like the module manifest is overwriting the app manifest.